# How to fix this raw query

Tags: android, sqlite

It is just giving an error like this

> Caused by : android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Please see the below code

```java
NoteDbHelper mDBHelper = new NoteDbHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db =  mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String arg = "2";
String query = "select * from " + NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + " where " + NoteEntry._ID + " =? ";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{arg});
int iTitle = c.getColumnIndex(NoteEntry.COL_TITLE);
String result = "";
result = result + c.getString(iTitle);
Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
c.close();
```

Revised code

```
NoteDbHelper mDBHelper = new NoteDbHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db =  mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String arg = "hi";
String query = "select * from " + NoteEntry.TABLE_NAME + " where " + NoteEntry.COL_TITLE + " =? ";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{arg});
int iTitle=c.getColumnIndex(NoteEntry.COL_TITLE);
String result = "";
result=result+c.getString(iTitle);
Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
c.close();
```

but still gives me the error : 
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: The documentation for [getColumnIndex](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) says: *Returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this statement:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{arg});
```

the cursor's index is right before the 1st row (if there is one).
You must call `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()` to position the index at the 1st row:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{arg});
String result = "";
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    int iTitle=c.getColumnIndex(NoteEntry.COL_TITLE);
    result=result+c.getString(iTitle);
    Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
c.close();
```